# Why does date format crash formatter?

Tags: date, swift3, nsdateformatter

Why I get to the `df.date()` line below, the app crashes with:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And I also see this:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

```
let mydate = "2016-12-27"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
newDate = df.date(from: mydate)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df = "MM/dd/yyyy"` ??

Comment: Should be `df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your code even compile because this line `df = "MM/dd/yyyy"` will give you compile error, [`df.date(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter/1409994-date) return optional `Date?` instance so it may be nil if your `dateFormat` and String date not match. Now your date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`. So change your code like this.

```
let mydate = "2016-12-27"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let date = df.date(from: mydate)  {
    df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let formattedDate = df.string(from: date)
    print(formattedDate)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was missing `.dateFormat` in the OP. However, I want the date to be in the format "MM/dd/yyyy". But as I mentioned, it crashes the app.

Comment: @4thSpace You can formatted date as string not as `Date` instance.

Comment: Not sure why that should restrict what the format will look like.

Comment: @4thSpace Check the edited answer if you want date format in `MM/dd/yyyy` but it is string.

Comment: I see. Now that the string is in the right format, how do I create a date instance from it? I guess it is just a matter of calling df.date().

Comment: @4thSpace I have already told you cannot set format of `Date` instance you can only get Foramted date as String using `DateFormatter`

Comment: @4thSpace Every time you print `Date` instance its output will be like `2016-12-27 14:40:46 +0000` and you can not change its format.

Comment: Thanks. I think you can help with a similar question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347426/how-to-handle-multiple-date-formats.