# How to compare two different date formats in swift

Tags: swift

I have two different date formats from the API for the same object one is "yyyy-MM-dd" and other one is "dd-MM-YYYY" how to differentiate, that object contains specific format.

Comment: You do not want to use `YYYY`. Use `yyyy` for the year.

Comment: Fine for year, how to compare two different date formats.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly is it that you wish to compare? Show some relevant code. Clearly explain what you need help with.

Comment: `var dueDate : String` this  string may contain date with `yyyy-MM-dd` or `dd-MM-yyyy` format, how can find that which format the string contains.

Comment: [Edit] your question. Don't put details in comments.

Comment: What are you going to do after you know which format it is? You are going to parse the date, right? In that case, this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347426/how-to-handle-multiple-date-formats).

Comment: Are you trying to convert the `String` to a `Date` but the string might be in one of two formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this may be worked for you.**

```
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // YOUR DATE FORMATE

 if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
       // IT CONTAIN YOUR DATE FORMATE
 }
```

Comment: Setting the timezone to UTC may or may not be appropriate.

Comment: @rmaddy I have update my answer please check it. it work fine.

Comment: @user3534730 How does this answer your question? This only deals with one format. Again, please update your question. It's extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let datestring = "2019-06-13" // try 13-06-2019 as well

let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var date = dateformatter.date(from: datestring)

if date == nil {
   dateformatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
   date = dateformatter.date(from: datestring)
 }
 print(date!)
```

there should be many other ways to this and hope this will help to you.

Comment: If this is what the OP wants, then this question is a duplicate of several other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about whatever the format is, You just need to populate it into Date Object by using date formatter. After that you can use that Date Object where ever you want to use. Like

```
let datestring = "2019-06-13"

let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var date1 = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

and for other type of date

```
let dateString = "13-06-2019"

let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
var date2 = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Now you got 2 date objects `date1` & `date2`, use these in your code without bothering about their previous formats.